# fs.rename callback executed twice?

Tags: node.js

I'm having an issue with `fs.rename`. The callback is executed twice. See this code:

```
log.d(_.keys(uploaded_photos));
async.each(_.keys(uploaded_photos), function(photo_key, callback) {
  var filename_array = uploaded_photos[photo_key].file.split('/');
  var filename = filename_array[filename_array.length-1];
  var tmp_file = __dirname + "/../public"+uploaded_photos[photo_key].file;
  log.d('Before readFile');
  async.waterfall([function(cb) {
    log.d('Inside waterfall');
    fs.rename(tmp_file, __dirname+"/../public/uploads/album_15_years/"+filename, function(err) {
      log.d('Moved file');
      cb(err);
    });
  }], function(err) {
    if(err) {
      log.e(err);
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  });
}, function() {
  var reply = {msg: "Answers and files saved successfully."};
  log.i(reply);
  res.send(201, reply);
});
```

This snippet of code outputs this:

```
[2014-05-15 11:51:55.932] [DEBUG] API.save_photos- ['photo1']
[2014-05-15 11:51:55.933] [DEBUG] API.save_photos- Before readFile
[2014-05-15 11:51:55.934] [DEBUG] API.save_photos- Moved file
[2014-05-15 11:51:55.935] [INFO] API.save_photos- { msg: 'Answers and files saved successfully.' }
[2014-05-15 11:51:55.936] [DEBUG] API.save_photos- Inside waterfall
[2014-05-15 11:51:55.937] [DEBUG] API.save_photos- Moved file
[2014-05-15 11:51:55.937] [ERROR] API.save_photos- { [Error: ENOENT, rename '/home/sbolduc/www/dashboard/routes/../public/uploads/tmp/1400169113201-0.01.PNG']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/sbolduc/www/dashboard/routes/../public/uploads/tmp/1400169113201-0.01.PNG' }
Error: ENOENT, rename '/home/sbolduc/www/dashboard/routes/../public/uploads/tmp/1400169113201-0.01.PNG'
POST /api/form201 52ms - 52b
```

As you can see, everything in the `async.each` gets called only once. Same as the log saying **Inside waterfall**. But everything inside `fs.rename` is called twice...

I tried using `fs.readfile` instead of `fs.rename` (and writing the file in the new folder and unlinking the old one) but `fs.readfile` is also called twice...

Do you have any idea of what's going on?

Comment: If I had to guess you might have dups in your `upload_photos`

Comment: An unrelated suggestion:  You should really be watching for users to pass in urls with `..` in the path and ignoring it.  You should also use full paths instead of `__dirname + "../path"`

Comment: Also: why use `waterfall()` at all when you just have one function in the array?

Comment: @mscdex I assumed he wants additional logic there. Good point jeremy

Comment: @Nate: `uploaded_photos` is an object with a single key. This key contains an object, with a `file` key equal to the path to the current file. @jeremy: I'll take good note. @mscdex: Nate is right, I simplified my code here, removing unnecessary operations (which I made sure don't impact the outcome if I remove them)

Comment: @SamuelBolduc Oh one more thing when `async.waterfall` errors you also  need to call `callback(err);` Don't use the if/else! Callback indicates when it's finished.

Comment: Thanks, forgot that. But it didn't change the outcome